# How to work with 2 HCSR04 Arduino Component?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Any ideas for the code of working with 2 different ultrasonic sensors? The idea is when either one of the sensors detects an obj in front of the sensor, it automatically turns on a buzzer. But for now, I only use the 2 ultrasonic sensors. This is my code, doesnt work as expected:

```
#define trigPin1 3
#define echoPin1 2
#define trigPin2 4
#define echoPin2 5

long duration, distance, RightSensor,LeftSensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
  RightSensor = distance;

  SonarSensor(trigPin2, echoPin2);
  LeftSensor = distance;

  Serial.print(LeftSensor);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.println(RightSensor);
  }

  void SonarSensor(int trigPin,int echoPin)
  {
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delay(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delay(2);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
}
```

[image: Concept]

Comment: This should work. I only checked the code, not the wiring. What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to approach this problem would be to make a function that returns the distance long. The code would look like this:

```
long duration, distance, RightSensor,LeftSensor;

void setup()
    {
    Serial.begin (9600);
    pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
    pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
    }
void SonarSensor(int trigPin,int echoPin)
    {
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
     delay(2);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
     delay(2);
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
      
     duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
     distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;
     return distance;
    }
void loop()
    {
    RightSensor = SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
    LeftSensor = SonarSensor(trigPin2, echoPin2);
    
    Serial.printIn(LeftSensor);
    Serial.print(" | ");
    Serial.printIn(RightSensor);
    }
```

If you are getting wrong readings try using this code for the function:

```
void SonarSensor(int trigPin,int echoPin) {
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  return distance;
```

If you want to use the original code, move the `void SonarSensor` before `void loop` and make distance a global long.